# I keep getting counter_cpu_share_used alerts in in Virtuozzo - do I have to take action?

Tags: cpu-usage, virtuozzo, linux-vserver

On my Hosteurope vServer, I keep getting these counter_cpu_share_used alerts in Virtuozzo, basically whenever I actively use my vServer.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VtWG.png)

As you can see, I get red alerts all the time. It happens I encode a video using ffmpeg, boot up my minecraft server (please don't judge me) or I install a wordpress plugin. Pretty much whenever I do something that uses the cpu for longer than a splitsecond.
However, my average cpu usage is pretty low.

Do I have to worry about these alerts?

Comment: Whether you have to worry about the alerts depends on what your service provider thinks of them. What did they say when you asked them the question?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to my hoster and this was their response (translated from German):

These alerts simple mean, that the CPU load was high. If this only happens temporarily, it is not a problem. If we noticed that your server was permanently under load, we would've contacted you..

**tl;dr** Nothing to worry about.